# Generating Quasi random sequences with customize interval e,g[-6,6] rather by default [0,1]

Tags: r

I am using Randtool box package of R to generate Quasi random sequences .
E.g

```
Halton(2,dim=2)
    Sobol(3,dim=3)..
```

but i am getting these sequences within `[0,1]` intervals.
For halton`(3,dim=3)` i am getting the following out put

```
0.50 0.3333333  0.2 
0.25 0.6666667  0.4
0.75 0.1111111  0.6
```

As we can clearly seen sequences are in `[0,1]` interval. How can we generate these quasi random sequences  with customize interval e.g `[-6,6]`?

For example we have random uniform function runif`(6,min=-6,max=6) this will give the random sequences between the interval`[-6,6]`.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Please fix this Q title...

Comment: @all : Tags has been Removed ,Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a random value a in the range [0, 1] and you want it to be in the range [x, y], do this:

b = a * (y - x) + x

for [-6, 6] you'll get:

b = a * (6 - (-6)) + (-6) = a * 12 - 6

This value will be between -6 and 6.

Comment: Does it effect on  actual sequencing algorithm? because unable to get the optimal solution ?

Comment: This is the generic solution for the situation you described. In many programming languages you don't set the range for the random number you want generated and only get a number in the range [0, 1]. Then you can expand this range yourself with the formula I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

To transform a [0,1] interval to [-6, 6], first multiply by 12 to get [0,12] and then subtract 6 to shift the interval to [-6, 6]. In short multiply every result from Halton or Sobol by 12, then subtract 6.